# Can you please help me find the eror on my javascript file undefined

Tags: javascript

when I console.log it it gives undefined but i checked 10 times bud cant find the erorr!

```js
let getBody = document.body;
let newElement = document.createElement("h1");

let date = new Date();
let currentHour = date.getHours();

let createTxtMsg;

if (currentHour >= 4 && currentHour < 10) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good Morning!";
} else if (currentHour >= 10 && currentHour < 12) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good Day!";
} else if (currentHour >= 12 && currentHour < 18) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good Afternoon";
} else if (currentHour >= 18 && currentHour < 22) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good evening";
} else if (currentHour >= 22 && currentHour < 4) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good night";
}

console.log(createTxtMsg)
let createEleTxt = document.createTextNode(createTxtMsg);

newElement.appendChild(createEleTxt);
getBody.appendChild(newElement);
```

Comment: Your `"Good night"` condition is impossible to be met.

Comment: Try `if (currentHour >= 22 || currentHour < 4)` instead

Comment: In your `else if` tests, you don't need the `>=` conditions. Since the conditions are tested in order, those are already ruled out by the previous `<` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your if..else if chain does not check for all conditions, as there is always the possiblity of the `currentHour` to be less than 4 or (instead of and) more than 22.

To simply account for that condition, simply just add an else statement, or add additional else if statements to handle the additional conditions

```
.
.
else if (currentHour< 4) {
  createTxtMsg = 'helloo';
}
.
.
```

Comment: `< 4` is supposed to print `Good night`.

Comment: I believe the OP knows the right string value to use

Answer (score 0):

There's logical error like comment said.

And I recommend you this approach. This is more readable and easy to understand.

```
    if (22 <= currentHour) {
      createTxtMsg = "Good night";
    } else if (18 <= currentHour) {
      createTxtMsg = "Good evening";
    } else if (12 <= currentHour) {
      createTxtMsg = "Good Afternoon";
    } else if (10 <= currentHour) {
      createTxtMsg = "Good Day!";
    } else if (4 <= currentHour) {
      createTxtMsg = "Good Morning!";
    } else {
      createTxtMsg = "Good night";
    }
```

**Compelete snippet:**

```js
let getBody = document.body;
let newElement = document.createElement("h1");

let date = new Date();
let currentHour = date.getHours();

let createTxtMsg;

if (22 <= currentHour) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good night";
} else if (18 <= currentHour) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good evening";
} else if (12 <= currentHour) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good Afternoon";
} else if (10 <= currentHour) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good Day!";
} else if (4 <= currentHour) {
  createTxtMsg = "Good Morning!";
} else {
  createTxtMsg = "Good night";
}

console.log(createTxtMsg)
let createEleTxt = document.createTextNode(createTxtMsg);

newElement.appendChild(createEleTxt);
getBody.appendChild(newElement);
```